# unicode string search

Tags: postgresql, search, unicode

I am using a Postgresql database. In my database there is one table `mumbaipropertydetails` in that one column zone has unicode data.

When I execute the query:

```
select mumbaipropertydetails."zone" 
from mumbaipropertydetails;
```

it gives output like this:

```
"\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940 \u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u0930\u0947"
"\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940 \u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u0930\u0947"
"\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940 \u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u0930\u0947"
"\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940 \u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u0930\u0947"
"\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940 \u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u0930\u0947"
"\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940 \u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u0930\u0947"
```

When I'm trying to execute another query like:

```
select mumbaipropertydetails.taxno 
from mumbaipropertydetails 
where mumbaipropertydetails."zone"= "\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940 
\u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u0930\u0947";
```

it gives an error like this

```
NOTICE:  identifier 
"\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940\u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u0930\u0947" 
will be truncated to
"\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940\u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u"

ERROR:  column "\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940 
\u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u" does not exist
LINE 1: ...opertydetails where mumbaipropertydetails."zone"= "\u092A\u0...
                                                         ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940 
\u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 99
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have confused single and double quote in your query.

You should query like this:

```
select mumbaipropertydetails.taxno
  from mumbaipropertydetails
  where
    mumbaipropertydetails.zone
    =
    E'\u092A\u093F\u0902\u092A\u0930\u0940 \u0935\u093E\u0918\u0947\u0930\u0947';
```

1. There's no need for quoting column names, if they are lower-case. If they're mixed or upper case you have to quote them in double quotes - `"`
2. Strings have to be quoted in single quotes - `'`
3. Strings that use backslash (`\`) for escaping, have to use a letter `E` before opening single quote, like in the example above.